# 2d array position track on processing

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, processing

This is a incomplete TILEWORLD game that I wrote by processing, which contains 20 obstacles, 10 holes, 10 tiles and one agent. agent moves randomly, and other objects dont move. In agentmove function, the agent goes into an obstacles, it stops， but I want the agent to avoid to go into the obstacles, so how do i keep track of the agents previous location, that if the agent's next move is the location where obstacle at, it avoid it?

```
int min_x = 0;
int min_y = 0; 
int max_x = 400;
int max_y = 600;
int grid_size = 10;
int Hoo[][] = new int[60][40];
int numhole=10;
int numtile =10;
int numobs=20;
PVector agent=getRandomLoc();
PVector hole1;
PVector tile;
PVector obstacle;
int x,y;
int i,j;
int a,b;
final int hole=1;
final int til=2;
final int obs=3;

final int STOPPED = 0;
final int RUNNING = 1;
int agentState = STOPPED;

void settings()
{
    size( max_x, max_y );
}

void setup() {
  ellipseMode( CORNER );
  agentState = RUNNING;

  for(x=0; x<60; x++){
    for(y=0;y<40;y++){
      Hoo[x][y]=0;
  }}

  while(numhole>0)
  {
    hole1=getRandomLoc();
    i=(int)hole1.x/grid_size;
    j=(int)hole1.y/grid_size;
    if(Hoo[j][i]==0){
      Hoo[j][i]=hole;
      numhole--;
    }
  }
 while(numobs>0)
  {
    obstacle=getRandomLoc();
    i=(int)obstacle.x/grid_size;
    j=(int)obstacle.y/grid_size;
    if(Hoo[j][i]==0){
      Hoo[j][i]=obs;
      numobs--;
}
}
while(numtile>0)
{
    tile=getRandomLoc();
    i=(int)tile.x/grid_size;
    j=(int)tile.y/grid_size;
    if(Hoo[j][i]==0){
      Hoo[j][i]=til;
      numtile--;
}
}
} 

void draw() {

  background( #ffffff );
  stroke( #cccccc );
  for ( int x=min_x; x<=max_x; x+=grid_size ) {
    line( x,min_y,x,max_y );
  }
  for ( int y=min_y; y<=max_y; y+=grid_size ) {
    line( min_x,y,max_x,y );
  }

  for(int x=0; x< 60; x++){
   for(int y=0; y<40; y++){
     if(Hoo[x][y]==obs){
      stroke( #cccccc );
      fill( #cccccc );
      rect( y*grid_size,x*grid_size, grid_size, grid_size );
  }}}

 for(int x=0; x< 60; x++){
   for(int y=0; y<40; y++){
     if(Hoo[x][y]==hole){
      stroke( #cccccc );
      fill( #000000 );
      rect( y*grid_size,x*grid_size, grid_size, grid_size );
      }}}

 for(int x=0; x< 60; x++){
   for(int y=0; y<40; y++){
     if(Hoo[x][y]==til){
      stroke( #cccccc );
      fill( #cc00cc );
      rect( y*grid_size,x*grid_size, grid_size, grid_size );
      noFill();
  }}}

 if ( agentState == RUNNING ) {
    makeRandomMove();
    agentmove();
    delay(100); 
  }
  stroke( #0000ff );
  fill( #0000ff );
  ellipse( agent.x, agent.y, grid_size, grid_size ); 


} 


void agentmove()
{

  int a=(int)agent.x/grid_size;
  int b=(int)agent.y/grid_size;

 if(Hoo[a][b]==obs)
   noLoop();

  if(Hoo[a][b]==hole)
  {
    noStroke();
    fill( #ffffff );
    ellipse( agent.x, agent.y, grid_size, grid_size );
    background(#000000);
  }
}

void mouseClicked() {
  if ( agentState == STOPPED ) {
    agentState = RUNNING;
  }
  else {
    agentState = STOPPED;
  }
} 

PVector getRandomLoc() {
  return( new PVector(
  ((int)random(min_x,max_x+1)/grid_size)*grid_size,
  ((int)random(min_y,max_y+1)/grid_size)*grid_size ));
} 

void makeRandomMove() {
  int direction = (int)random( 0,4 );
  switch( direction ) {
  case 0: // north
    agent.y -= grid_size;
    if ( agent.y < min_y ) {
      agent.y = max_y - grid_size;
    }
    break;
  case 1: // west
    agent.x -= grid_size;
    if ( agent.x < min_x ) {
      agent.x = max_x - grid_size;
    }
    break;
  case 2: // south
    agent.y += grid_size;
    if ( agent.y > max_y ) {
      agent.y = min_y;
    }
    break;
  case 3: // east
    agent.x += grid_size;
    if ( agent.x > max_x ) {
      agent.x = min_x;
    }
    break;
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way that you could go about this, assuming that your agent can only move 1 space:

- Take current agent position.
- Check the current position +1 or -1 (in the direction that they are moving) to see if it is a valid position.
- If it is, carry on. If it isn't, stop the movement method.

For example: If the agent is at position (0,0), and  they are moving down 1 space. Check the position (1,0) to see what is at that space. If it is a wall/out of bounds, return out of the move method early.

```
 //Agent position is at Hoo[0][0] - Lets represent it with a/b
 //A random wall was generated at Hoo[1][0]
 //We are attempting to move down 1 space.

 if (Hoo[a + 1][b] == obs){

   //The position has an obstacle. Return/deny movement

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

- You have the agent's position in the grid as an `[x,y]` position.
- You have a grid with obstacles with their own `[x,y]` positions.
- So to check whether the agent is about to hit an obstacle to the right, you just have to check whether the grid has an obstacle at the `[x+1,y]` position.

Here's a little example that does that:

```
boolean[][] grid = new boolean[3][3];
int playerX = 0;
int playerY = 0;

void setup() {
  grid[1][1] = true;
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  drawGrid();
  drawPlayer();
}

void keyPressed() {
  if (keyCode == UP) {
    up();
  } else if (keyCode == DOWN) {
    down();
  } else if (keyCode == LEFT) {
    left();
  } else if (keyCode == RIGHT) {
    right();
  }
}

void up() {
  //don't let the player move off the screen
  if (playerY > 0) {
    //don't let the player move over an occupied cell
    if (!grid[playerX][playerY-1]) {
      //move the player
      playerY--;
    }
  }
}

void down() {

  //don't let the player move off the screen
  if (playerY < 2) {
    //don't let the player move over an occupied cell
    if (!grid[playerX][playerY+1]) {
      //move the player
      playerY++;
    }
  }
}

void left() {
  //don't let the player move off the screen
  if (playerX > 0) {
    //don't let the player move over an occupied cell
    if (!grid[playerX-1][playerY]) {
      //move the player
      playerX--;
    }
  }
}

void right() {
  //don't let the player move off the screen
  if (playerX < 2) {
    //don't let the player move over an occupied cell
    if (!grid[playerX+1][playerY]) {
      //move the player
      playerX++;
    }
  }
}


void drawGrid() {

  //loop through each column
  for (int column = 0; column < grid.length; column++) {

    //loop through each row
    for (int row = 0; row < grid[column].length; row++) {

      float w = width/3.0; //width of cell
      float h = height/3.0; //height of cell
      float x = column * w; //x of square
      float y = row * h; //y of square

      if (grid[column][row]) {
        //if grid is populated, draw black
        fill(0);
      } else {
        //if grid is populated, draw white
        fill(255);
      }

      //draw the grid cell
      rect(x, y, w, h);
    }
  }
}

void drawPlayer() {

  float w = width/3.0; //width of cell
  float h = height/3.0; //height of cell
  float x = playerX * w; //x of square
  float y = playerY * h; //y of square

  //green
  fill(0, 255, 0);

  //draw the player cell
  rect(x, y, w, h);
}
```